# How can I open all the files in all the subdirectories of a folder?

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to recursively open all the files in a folder, including its directories. I've been playing around with `open /path/to/folder/*`, and this will open all the files inside that folder but not include the sub-directories.

If I had a folder tree that looked like this:

```
Folder
>subfolder1
>>file1.jpg
>>file2.jpg
>subfolder2
>>file1.jpg
>>file2.jpg
>subfolder3
>>file.jpg
```

How could I open all the files in one terminal command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest

```
find . | xargs open
```

Comment: Note that this has the potential to massively slow down / crash your system if you run it in the wrong folder... =P It won't ask if you really want to open every single file on your computer.

Comment: As a side note, you can also use "find ./*/*.jpg | xargs open" if there are non jpg files that you want to ignore.

Comment: I would rather use `find . -name "*.jpg"`